# Rubik's cube on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

May a person solve a [rubik's cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube) on Shabbos?

Comment: Why not? What *m'lacha* could it possibly be construed as? Are you referring to a Rubik's Cube that uses words instead of colors?

Comment: The question need not be a complicated one.  I think the answer is just "yes; I've never seen anyone say it's a problem."

Comment: Perhaps it could be muktzeh?

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that it is permitted, see Shemiras Shabbas K'Hilchasa 16:24 which discusses a "two dimensional" puzzle where one rearranges the pieces which are attached to a frame and rules that it is permitted. It would seem that rubix cube is even easier to permit since there is no actual picture formed.

For what it is worth I think that it is an excellent question, because while none of them seem to quite fit, solving a rubix cube reminds us of a number of melachos.

Answer (score 0):

I saw from the link below that it is allowed, but for Adults it is not the Sabbath honour that the adults  will play (note if it's creating a picture by solving the cube that is something else)

http://shulchanharav.com/contents.asp?fid=185&av=12386

but [somewhere else](https://theshc.org/rubiks-cube-on-shabbat/) I saw this might be Borer

> As we have shown, there are a few reasons to assume that Borer would
>   apply to the Rubik’s Cube, and thus, since it may infringe on a Torah
>   prohibition, adults should refrain from playing with it. This too was
>   the ruling of HaRav Shlomo Miller שליט”א. As for children, while
>   there is room to be lenient if necessary, it would obviously be proper
>   Hinuch to avoid it.

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote.

Comment: The first article explicitly says it is not borer.

Comment: others allowing: https://dinonline.org/2011/09/04/rubiks-cube-on-shabbos/ and https://din.org.il/2016/04/03/childrens-games-on-shabbos/?lang=en

Comment: That article doesn't give "a few reasons to assume that Borer would apply to the Rubik’s Cube". It gives a few reasons to assume that borer wouldn't apply (one big one in a footnote not in the main text) and then rejects them all.  You have to accept _all_ of his arguments if it's going to be borer.